# add checkbox before label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to markup simple form on the bootstrap. This code from bootstrap docs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>      
</form>
```

How can I add a checkbox before label? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HWaKm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label><input type="checkbox" /> A checkbox</label>
    </div>
</div>
```